# Problems with spacing and creating new lines

Tags: html, css, search, spacing

I have been modifying SourceBans to look more modern and I came into a little pickle
That is that I want the search field to be in the right below the links on the top like this: [image]

Here's a live version of the current page: [☻](http://potatofactory.ta0soft.com/panel/)

Additional Resources:

- [CSS](http://potatofactory.ta0soft.com/panel/themes/default/css/css.php)
- [Searchbar Sourcecode](http://potatofactory.ta0soft.com/panel/themes/default/searchbar.preview)

Comment: remove the margin top from the #nav

Comment: Not gonna work cause nav will be fill with content when you login

Comment: not removed `width: 300px;` from `#search` yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to the *button* input and remove `width: 300px; float: left;` from the `#search`.

That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

- remove `float: left;` from both `#nav` and `#search`
- remove `width` from  `#search`
- make your input `width:100%`

(and a little padding-top)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:

```
    /*
    This container do not need to float: left, just use this:
    */
    #search
    {
       /* margin-left: 590px; my mistake ;) */
        padding: 2px 0 0;
        text-align: left;
        width: 300px;
    }

/* remove default marging and padding of the form element */
#search form
{
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}

/* grow searchbox to full width, if wanted */
#search .searchbox
{
   width: 100%;
}
```